# ObjectDeletedException when i move items from one bag to another

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an invoice object that has several invoice items. Based on user selection i need to move some of the items from one invoice to another.
I am using MySql and Hibernate.

Invoice items are defined to be lazy loaded as follows:

In Java I do the following:

```
Invoice newInvoice = new Invoice();
iter = invoice.getPurchasableItems().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){ // item that is not purchased into new invoice
    InvoiceItem item = iter.next();
    invoice.getItems().remove(item);
    newInvoice.addItem(item);
}
```

Then i save the two invoices:

```
iter = newInvoice.getItems().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){ 
    InvoiceItem item = iter.next();
    session.saveOrUpdate(item);
}
iter = invoice.getItems().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
    InvoiceItem item = iter.next();
    session.saveOrUpdate(item);
}
session.commit();
```

and i get ObjectDeletedException.  I do not believe i have any other reference to the invoice items other than moving them from one invoice to the other.  I do this because i want to make sure i am not ended up with a lot of un-used IDs for the invoice item table.

Can you suggest a way to fix this problem?

Comment: <bag name="items" table="INVOICE_ITEM" cascade="all,delete-orphan" lazy="true">

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has nothing to do with your problem but your first while is probably modifying the collection that you are iterating. You should probably use the remove() method from the iterator.

Then changing the InvoiceItem from one bag to another is not enough you need to also update you invoiceItem, I don't know if you have a ManyToMany on ManyToOne in your InvoiceItem, but I think you will have to set both side of the relation.

```
Invoice newInvoice = new Invoice();
iter = invoice.getPurchasableItems().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){ // item that is not purchased into new invoice
    InvoiceItem item = iter.next();
    iter.remove();
    item.setInvoice(newInvoice);
    newInvoice.addItem(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I am removing item from invoice and not the iterator.. invoice.getItems().remove(item) .... and the relationship is one-to-many and not bi-directional.  and cascade="all,delete-orphan"   ... Thanks